# Prove or disprove: $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am trying to determine whether the following statement is true or false:

Let $f(x)$ be an unbounded non decreasing function.

Define $g(x) =  f(x) - \frac{f(x)}{\cos \left(\tfrac{1}{f(x)}\right)}$.

Prove or disprove:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x) = 0$.

After trying to find counter examples I believe the statement is true.

I have tried to prove the statement using the squeeze theorem but it didn't got me much further.

Any hints will be appericiated.

Comment: By the way, how is \tfrac different from \frac?

Comment: @insipidintegrator https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343033/when-to-use-tfrac

Comment: Thanks @IgorRivin

Comment: @insipidintegrator As used here, there's no difference.  When frac is used in-line, it uses tfrac.  When frac is used in display mode, it uses dfrac.  If you want to force the software to use one in the other mode, you can specify it.  (But think veery carefully before using dfrac in-line)

Comment: Thanks @BrianMoehring

Comment: Hint: $\cos(x)\geq 1-x^2$

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitution $f(x) = \frac1u,$ and evaluate the resulting expression in $u$ as $u$ goes to $0$ (using L'Hopital, e.g.)

Comment: This is of course not true

Comment: @aaabbb Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @IgorRivin I for one knew exactly what you meant. And the answer by R. Szwarc cites your suggestion, going through more of the details. [I'll +1 your answer to counteract naive downvote.]

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you! It is peculiar that the answer god multiple downvotes about two minutes after I posted it. Apparently, many here subscribe to the principle "I don't understand it, so it must be wrong".

Answer (score 2):

As $f(x)$ is nondecreasing and unbounded then $f(x)\nearrow \infty.$ Therefore  $u=f((x)^{-1}\to 0^+$ (as suggested by Igor Rivin). The limit takes the form $$\lim_{u\to 0^+} {1\over u}\left (1-{1\over \cos u}\right )=\lim_{u\to 0^+} {\cos u-1\over u}{1\over \cos u } $$ The limit of the first fraction is by definition equal $ (\cos)'(0)=-\sin 0=0$ while the second fraction tends to $1.$ Hence the result is equal $0.$